# Difference: "the product being sold" and "the product sold"

Tags: grammar, syntax, participles

> The commercial is focused on the embarrassment that someone can experience when the product **being** sold isn’t used.

Is it correct or is there any difference if I use delete "being" from the original sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, "being sold" is present continuous tense. The product is currently being sold and it is in an ongoing state of being sold. Simply "sold" is past tense. The product was sold at some time in the past.

In context, the difference may or may not matter. Presumably the product is still being sold. But using the past tense doesn't necessarily mean that it is not being sold any more. It could have been sold in the past and is now no longer being sold. But it could have been sold in the past and is still being sold.

Like suppose you were talking about something that happened five years ago and they you asked, "Where did you live five years ago?" The person replies, "Five years ago I lived in Ohio." With no further information, that tells us nothing about where he lives today. He might still live in Ohio, or he might have moved during the past five years.